# Сделать общую тень у совмещенных блоков

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть задача: сделать тень у двух блоков таким образом, чтобы они были только в тех местах, где нарисованы стрелки и не "залазили" друг на друга и на блоки в месте пересечения этих двух блоков.

Пока на ум приходят разные решения через before,after и дополнительные div'ы в разметке. Хотелось бы как-то "поэлегантнее" решить эту задачу. Есть какие-нибудь идеи?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариант попроще, но не поддерживается в IE.

```css
.green{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background-color:green;
}
.red{
  width:150px;
  height:150px;
  background-color:red;
}
.block{
  filter:drop-shadow(0 0 7px #000);
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="green"></div>
  <div class="red"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.a {
  position: relative;
  background: green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.b {
  background: red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}

.a::after {
  content: '';
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 16px black;
}

.b::after {
  content: '';
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 16px black;
}
```

```html
<div class="con">
  <div class="a"></div>
  <div class="b"></div>
</div>
```